# Trying to retrieve arraylist from session in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm using HttpSession to store ArrayList `userList` as session attribute from original Servlet before passing it to JSP. It is then called in the next JSP and then called to another Servlet from that JSP.

Servlet 1 -> JSP1 -> JSP2 -> Servlet 2

In Servlet 1, I've set it to session :

```
if (!userList.isEmpty()) {
    session.setAttribute("userList", userList); 
}
```

I iterate it in JSP 1 and JSP 2 and call it again in Servlet 2. I need the ArrayList to be used as a parameter in another method in servlet 2.

```
EditStudentForm edt = (EditStudentForm)form;
List<UserApplication> studtList = new ArrayList<UserApplication>();
if ((session.getAttribute("userList")) instanceof List){
    studtList = (ArrayList<UserApplication>)request.getSession().getAttribute("userList");
}
try {
    uaDAO.editUser(edt,studtList);
    action_forward = EDITSUCCESS;
}
```

It looks like the casting is not really working because the size of the ArrayList is 1 (I'm expecting a size of at least 30)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: umm..  a) is this all within a single request b) if it is, why aren't you saving it as a request attribute c) if not, what is your mechanism from going to servlet from a jsp d) even if it is, why would you go to servlet from a jsp?

Comment: If it's in the session, it's in the session. Are you sure you're accessing the data you think you are? Also, don't cast to `ArrayList` if you're checking for a `List`--cast to `List`.

Comment: @eis Because servlets are where all the back-end work occurs, not in JSPs, which are the presentation layer. Although this sounds more like Struts than servlets.

Comment: @DaveNewton servlets are typically front controllers, not "where all the back-end work occurs". but either or, I'm curious why would you go back to a servlet from a jsp in a request chain.

Comment: @eis I find it unlikely the "servlet" is accessed by anything other than a post from the JSP, as evidenced by the code accessing the form, which is most likely a Struts form, or at least written by somebody using Struts terminology in their own framework. By "where all the back-end work occurs" I mean the marshalling of data from the web layer to business layer, and vice-versa. And that *is* what they should be used for in a servlet-based application, unless you're implementing another framework on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is working fine and is unrelated to the size of the list. Casting just tells you that what you've stored in `userList` is really an ArrayList. If the size is different, then it seems to imply there is a bug in your logic somewhere else. Do you change the list referred to by the variable `userList` after calling `session.setAttribute()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to `List<UserApplication>`.